# Do you need a google workspace account to retrieve a TXT record for a custom google domain name?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting, domain-name

I have been attempting to learn web development skills by making my own website (ever so slowly and painfully) which has eventually led me to create a react firebase site. I bought a custom domain name from google domains, and to verify it with firebase I need to add a TXT record. From all my searching it seems I need to buy a google workspace membership to retrieve this TXT record? Is this true??? I would really like to avoid spending any more money and would love any advice or assistance, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add DNS records [directly](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-a-resource-record) in Google Domains.